# Springboot profile and running some tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-profiles

On a springboot application  I have unit and integration tests. What I want is to control which group of tests to run and when. I mean running units **OR** integration tests, **BUT** not both.

I know it is possible through maven, but I was wondering if **Spring Profile** can be used to achieve this. I mean something like, marking unit tests in one profile, and integration tests in another profile. And at run time I supply a profile, which triggers only running those tests that belongs to that profile.

Comment: Of course its possible with `@ActiveProfiles("profilename")` annotation. give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired behavior with the following addition to build.gradle:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    exclude "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"
    testLogging {
        events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    description = "Execute integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    include "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"
    testLogging {
        events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
    }
}
check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

This will create *test* and *integrationTest* under verification task. Now you can run either one or the other or both by running the *check* task. The integration tests must have IntTest or IT in the class name.

Also, don't forget to add the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.2"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can group these two kinds of tests by Spring profile.
You will have to create an `application.properties` specific to unit tests and another one specific to integration tests if you want to run one or the other.
For example `application-ut.properties` and `application-it.properties` with each one their specificities.

Then you should specify `@ActiveProfiles` for each test class according to their nature.

For integration test classes, for example :

```
@ActiveProfiles("it")
public class FooIntegrationTest {}

@ActiveProfiles("it")
public class BarIntegrationTest {}
```

For unit test classes, for example :

```
@ActiveProfiles("ut")
public class FooTest {}

@ActiveProfiles("ut")
public class BarTest {}
```

Comment: I tried it, and doesn't work. I have created a profile named "e2e" and a properties file named "application-e2e.properties" (which is literally empty). And then I tried with "mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=e2e". But its running all tests.

Comment: ActiveProfiles declares only which profiles should be activated when this test is being run. And not what profile needs to be active for this test to run.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html